# Design of a Wrapper Class in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, wrapper

I have to work with an old class with a very clumsy interface. Since I cannot change it and am reliant to it, I want to build a wrapper, offering a clean interface. Let's say I have a class **ClumsyClass**. Basically, I have three approaches:

**1. Reference Member**

```
    Class Wrapper {
      public:
        Wrapper (ClumsyClass& clumsyClass)
          : m_clumsyClass(clumsyClass)
        { }

        int getSmth() {
          return m_clumsyClass.getSmth();
        }

        private:
          ClumsyClass& m_clumsyClass;
}
```

**2. Pointer Member**

```
    Class Wrapper {
      public:
        Wrapper (ClumsyClass* clumsyClass)
          : m_clumsyClass(clumsyClass)
        { }

        int getSmth() {
          return m_clumsyClass->getSmth();
        }

        private:
          ClumsyClass* m_clumsyClass;
}
```

**3. Inheritance**

```
    Class Wrapper : public ClumsyClass {
    ...
}
```

Which approach is the "cleanest" way to implement a wrapper? I prefer the third one, but when I already have a ClumsyClass object and then create a Wrapper object (copy constructor), more memory will be needed (since an instance of the original class is necessary in my case).

Comment: You want to apply the [Pointer to Implementation (PIMPL)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) idiom.

Comment: 4. Can't you have an instance as member without passing it in the constructor?

Comment: Is your wrapper class supposed to have the ownership of existing ClumsyClass object? If yes, then std::move the ClumsyClass object into your wrapper class.

Comment: You might want to apply the [facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Comment: Never use reference members for any purpose, full stop. Only use public inheritance to express [is-a relationship](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a). This kills 2 out of 3 I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid 3 as it fails to encapsulate `ClumsyClass`. Users of `Wrapper` can, intentionally or otherwise, directly access the "clumsy" interface of `ClumsyClass` which is what you are trying to avoid. Prefer composition over inheritance.

The differences between 1. and 2. are minor. Using a reference member makes the wrapper less flexible. The class is not assignable, you can't reseat the reference and replace it with a different instance of `ClumsyClass` and the member can't be null. These could be good or bad things depending on your requirements.

But as mentioned in comments, the default choice should probably be to have `ClumsyClass` as a by-value member of `Wrapper`:

```
class Wrapper {
  public:
    // possible constructors
    //Wrapper(const ClumsyClass& cc) : m_clumsyClass(cc) {} // copy 
    //Wrapper(ClumsyClass&& cc) : m_clumsyClass(std::move(cc)) {}  // move 
    int getSmth() { return m_clumsyClass.getSmth(); }

  private:
    ClumsyClass m_clumsyClass;
};
```

There are number of reasons why this might not be possible or desirable in your particular use case and then you can fall-back to option 1 or 2. The decision depends mostly on ownership. Should `Wrapper` "own" the `ClumsyClass` or does the instance of `ClumsyClass` have a lifetime outside that of `Wrapper`?

One potential downside of using a direct member is you can no-longer hide the implementation of `ClumsyClass` behind a forward declaration so you lose some of the encapsulation of `ClumsyClass`. It is worth noting that one way of solving this is to extract out an abstract base class "interface" that `Wrapper` inherits from. Something like:

```
class IWrapper {
  public:
    virtual ~IWrapper() {}
    virtual int getSmth() = 0;
};
```

which might provide additional benefits like testability.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the constraints that you have mentioned that this could be a feasible approach:

Create an interface with the methods you like to have

```
struct IMyMethods 
{
  virtual int getOther() = 0;
  ...
  virtual ~IMyMethods() {};
};
```

Now create a new class deriving from your class and the interface you want to use on the class where you add the implementation of the interface

```
class MyAgileClass : public ClumsyClass, IMyMethods
{
public:
   MyAgileClass(/*same args as for ClumsyClass*/)
   {}
   ~MyAgileClass() 
   {}

   virtual int getOther() 
   {
     return getSmth(); // clumsy class function
   }
   ...
};
```

You can now either access the ClumsyClass directly or via the simplified interface